# Count number of occurrences by Name

Tags: html, sql

First timer here so please excuse me if my question is somewhat confusing. I am attempting to display things in a dynamic table using data pulled from a SQL table and I am having difficulty figuring out the logic.

The table structure looks something like this

```
NAME   Homeruns  Hits    Bunts   Total

Jeff       0       3       1       4

Sally      2       4       0       6

John       3       7       0       10
```

The data in the table is structured in a way that the type of play being made (Home run, hit, bunt, etc) is in a single column. I'll call this column PLAY. The name is in a separate column. This column will be called NAME. Table name is BASEBALL.

Comment: So would like to just get all the data from the table? or do you want to include only a certain set...i.e individuals with total > 6

Comment: please ask clearly what you want to do. You were on the right track with this question

Comment: What do you want just give an example of your expected output.We would try our best to solve it

Comment: sorry for the confusion, Gordon Linoff was able to answer my question. What I was trying to do was take the results from the SQL query and put it in a HTML table (using Visual C#), which I was able to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a pivoting query.  You can do this in standard SQL with aggregation:

```
select name,
       sum(case when play = 'HomeRun' then 1 else 0 end) as HomeRun,
       sum(case when play = 'hit' then 1 else 0 end) as Hit,
       sum(case when play = 'bunt' then 1 else 0 end) as Bunt,
       count(*) as Total
from baseball bb
group by name;
```

This is a pretty simple SQL query, so I'm guessing your expertise is less on the database side than on the programming side.  I would suggest that you take the time to learn the SQL language properly.